# Which travellers in Mongolia have to register, and how?

Tags: legal, regulations, mongolia, registration

When I was applying for my visa to Mongolia a couple of days ago the form mentioned something about registering within three days when staying more than thirty days.

But the English was not great and could be interpreted in a couple of ways, also I was in a hurry. I wish I could quote its exact wording.

But now I'm in Mongolia and it's my second day and I've just remembered it.

Since I have a standard 30-day tourist visa is there any chance I need to register tomorrow? If so, how? With the local police?

Then what if I extend my visa later on beyond 30 days? I think I'll want to because I'll be due to leave on Christmas Day the way I calculate it.

**What are the actual rules/laws about registering for tourists in Mongolia?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The registration requirement for Mongolia is, as you say, and as [several](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_973.html) other sources [quote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Mongolia), for tourists who plan to stay longer than 30 days there. They have to register within 4 days of arrival. Since you have got a thirty day visa, I can only assume that you do not plan to stay longer than 30 days, and therefore do not need to register.

If you currently plan to not overstay 30 days, but change your mind later, I would suggest that you go and talk to the [immigration agency](http://www.immigration.gov.mn/) at that point in time. You would have to do so anyhow in order not to violate your visa status.

Comment: Hmm I don't want to violate it or to overstay, but I'm still seriously considering extending it.